# Why childrenRectChanged is not emitted, but calling childrenRect "fixes" it?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickitem

### Goal

I need to know when and how the collective geometry of the children of `Foo`, a subclass of [`QQuickItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html), changes.

### Problem

I have connected a lambda to the `QQuickItem::childrenRectChanged` signal, but it is never emitted. Strangely enough, if I call `childrenRect` somewhere, the signal starts getting emitted. `childrenRect` is a getter method, not a setter, so I see no reason for this "fix".

### Question

Why a seemingly unrelevant call "fixes" the emition of the signal and how to make this work as expected without calling `childrenRect`?

### Reproducible example

Here is an example I have prepared to demonstrate the issue:

**Foo.h**

```
#include <QQuickItem>

class Foo : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Foo(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr) :
        QQuickItem(parent) {
        childrenRect(); // After commenting this childrenRectChanged is not emitted anymore
        connect(this, &Foo::childrenRectChanged, [this](){
            qDebug() << childrenRect();
        });
    }
};
```

The class is registered in **main.cpp** like this:

```
qmlRegisterType<Foo>("Foo", 1, 0, "Foo");
```

and used in **main.qml** in the following way:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import Foo 1.0

Window {
    width: 300; height: 400; visible: true; color: "black"
    title: qsTr("Children Rect")

    Foo {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            anchors.bottom: lightMid.top
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: 50; height: width; radius: 0.5*width
            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: lightMid

            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 50; height: width; radius: 0.5*width
            color: "yellow"
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.top: lightMid.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: 50; height: width; radius: 0.5*width
            color: "green"
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

The documentation of [`QQuickItem::childrenRect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#childrenRect-prop)  says:

> This property holds the collective position and size of the item's
> children.
>
> This property is useful if you need to access the collective geometry
> of an item's children in order to correctly size the item.
>
> Access functions:
>
> QRectF    childrenRect()

However, as @Amfasis mentioned in the comments, this method is not just a simple getter. Here is [`the code`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp.html#_ZN10QQuickItem12childrenRectEv):

```
QRectF QQuickItem::childrenRect()
{
    Q_D(QQuickItem);
    if (!d->extra.isAllocated() || !d->extra->contents) {
        d->extra.value().contents = new QQuickContents(this);
        if (d->componentComplete)
            d->extra->contents->complete();
    }
    return d->extra->contents->rectF();
}
```

Comment: As you can see from [woboq](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp.html#_ZN10QQuickItem12childrenRectEv) it is not a simple getter, but I'm unsure how this affects your situation

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know the geometry? The example that you give can probably rewritten with a ColumnLayout, but how far from your real problem is this reduced example?

Comment: @Amfasis, _how far from your real problem is this reduced example?_ quite far. In fact the reimplementation of `itemChange` is not just a random guess. In the real case I use `ItemChildAddedChange` to connect the signals of `Foo`'s children of a particular type to `Foo`'s slots. Using a layout inside `Foo` in QML prevents `Foo` from knowing when an item is added, as this item would not be a child of `Foo` anymore, but a child of the layout. So, I need all items as direct children of `Foo`.

Comment: If it's just about the geometry you could opt for writing your own layout: https://blog.rburchell.com/2012/05/writing-layout-in-qml.html or maybe you can draw inspiration from this link

Comment: @Amfasis, thank you for the link! However, that does not help me further, as it describes how to create a layout in QML. I need to know the change in childrens' geometry in a C++ class, which is then use in QML.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this problem in the Qt 5.15. As an alternate, you can use the `QQuickItem::widthChanged` and `QQuickItem::heightChanged` signals on `itemChange(ItemChange change, const ItemChangeData &)` when `change == QQuickItem::ItemChange::ItemChildAddedChange`. The `childrenRectChanged` seems more efficient while the proposed alternate way is more accurate.